# EmguCV First Principal Component

Tags: c#, pca, emgucv

I am working on hand detection, tracking and recognition and i need to calculate the First Principal Component. I am using C# and EmguCV. My experience with PCA is way limited and I've been looking for documentation, tutorials and code on the matter and can't get one suitable...

The only thing I need to do is get the principal orientation of the hand (as i understand it, it's the first principal component).

Can someone help me understand how to calculate it from a binary image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257502/Creating-Your-First-EMGU-Image-Processing-Project

Comment: and this (more relevant) http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/394909/Get-Palm-Hand-Region-from-Binary-Image-on-Csharp-E

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already do hand segmentation and Contour analysis to detect the hand and fingers. I am also using Hu moments for roatition invariant characteristics of the binarized image. But i need to get the object's (hand) principal orientation, i was told i could achieve it from PCA analysis... The orientation itself is my problem.

Comment: have you read http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse576/book/ch3.pdf it's pretty detailed but not code-y more scientific

Comment: www-prima.imag.fr/Prima/jlc/papers/PUI97.Crowley.pdf this also gives a formula

Comment: Thank you for the documentation Rachel. It helps understanding the math behind PCA... After more research I know that openCV/emguCV implement PCA through the cvCaclPCA or eigenObjectRecognizer. I'm more interested in the first, because my aim is to get the principal orientation of the object, but i can't get it to work and can't find no useful documentation...

Answer (score 1):

look at:
http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3066#p6497

I am no familiar with PCA using EmguCV. I would use Accord.NET C# library that has built in class: PrincipalComponentAnalysis.cs

so there as steps:

```
get image data of an image as double[,] (that is your sourceMatrix)

var pca = new PrincipalComponentAnalysis(sourceMatrix, AnalysisMethod.Center);
pca.Compute();
double[,] components = pca.Transform(sourceMatrix, 0.8f, true); //your image with 80% information kept

convert components to your image
```

you could also set the number of components instead of information threshold